# Noise pdf Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Why the probability distribution function of the noise in a channel is Gaussian (normal distribution)?
Intuitive discussion is appreciated.

Comment: As is the case with many mathematical models, the Gaussian does not fit the reality all that well, and often the fit is quite poor. But it is a model that is relatively easy to work with.

Comment: It makes sense but why they choose normal distribution for noise and gaussian for ease. Would there be any specific property of noise that make it normally distributed

Comment: If one assumes that the actual noise is a sum of a lot of independent identically distributed little noises, then one can give a mathematical reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may think of noise as the result of many, many independant small random influences adding up. Then the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) says that this can be approximated by the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Another important property of Gaussian noise, is that if you pass it through a linear filter, the output will be Gaussian. So, many small independent sources of the noise, passing through linear filters, will result in Gaussian noise.